# BCD of a decimal to Hexadecimal

Tags: hex, data-conversion, bcd, number-systems

I have this problem:

convert: 17535455(base 10) to BCD to hexadecimal
(another way of saying it: convert the BCD of 17535455(base 10) to Hexadecimal)

should I convert the BCD directly to Hexadecimal? If that would be the case then the answer would also be 17535455(base 16) ?

or could their be another interpretation for this?

Comment: what language? do You have arithmetic library?

Comment: BCD in hex 'for eyes' is similar to ASCII (string) representation, one hex digit (half of byte) is human readable 'normal' digit

Comment: BCD as in Binary-Coded Decimal Form.

Comment: BCD is base16. `0x17535455` in your case. So it's a bit unclear as to what *conversion to hexadecimal* implies.

Comment: or should I do : BCD -> Decimal -> binary -> hexadecimal?

Comment: there is no binary / decimal distinction. All numbers are in reality the same. Distinct internal form (yes, BCD i kind of) and externel formatting for human

Comment: homework assignment? maybe it meant *convert 17535455(base 10) to BCD _and_ to hexadecimal*...